# How to update database after cloning an event in fullcalendar using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm relatively new to programming and some help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using fullcalendar and have got it to the point where I can add, remove & drag and drop events. My last requirement is to be able to clone events for quicker management.

I am using the following code to clone events (taken from a previous post). Currently this does not save to the database:

```
     eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
     if (!copyKey) return;
     var eClone = {
       id: event.id+1,
       title: event.title,
       tooling: event.tooling,
       start: event.start,
       end: event.end
     };
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eClone);
 },
```

An example piece of code I have used to update my SQL database is here:

```
eventDrop:function(event)
{
 var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
 var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
 var title = event.title;
 var tooling = event.tooling;
 var id = event.id;
 $.ajax({
  url:"update.php",
  type:"POST",
  data:{title:title, tooling:tooling, start:start, end:end, id:id},
  success:function()
  {
   calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  }
 });
},
```

My main confusion is how to use AJAX for my clone function, also making sure to increment the id when a new event is created.

Comment: Hi there, have you consider to use JQuery ? ( Javascript framework with ajax powerfull support )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to make use of insert.php rather than update.php...

Final working code:

```
     eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view)
 {
     if (!copyKey) return;
     var eClone = {
       id: event.id,
       title: event.title,
       tooling: event.tooling,
       start: event.start,
       end: event.end
     };
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eClone);
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var tooling = event.tooling;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"insert.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, tooling:tooling, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eClone);
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
      }
     });
 },
```